# Using multiple condition query with order by

Tags: c#, sql

I have multiple if conditions for my query, so that the user can search from the database based on drop down list selection, for example I want to get the users that have pc or not and if they have laptop or not,

using a drop down list which has 3 options all, yes and no.

everything is working fine but I have one issue with sorting, as seen below on my code in the command I can't add (order by) at the end of the query because I will have an error if I selected one of the drop down lists,

is there any idea how to use order by in this scenario,

any help will be appreciated.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_pc" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="all" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="yes" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="no" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_laptop" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="all" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="yes" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="no" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

string command = "SELECT user_name, user_full_name from users_table where user_name > 0";

if (Int32.Parse(DropDownList_pc.SelectedItem.Value) == 2)
{
    command += " and user_pc >= 1";
}
else if (Int32.Parse(DropDownList_pc.SelectedItem.Value) == 3)
{
    command += " and user_pc = 0";
}
   
if (Int32.Parse(DropDownList_laptop.SelectedItem.Value) == 2)
{
    command += " and user_laptop >= 1";
}
else if (Int32.Parse(DropDownList_laptop.SelectedItem.Value) == 3)
{
    command += " and user_laptop = 0";
}
```

Comment: Which column would you like to order by? And is that based on some selection made by the user? If so, how?

Comment: you say "I can't add (order by) at the end of the query", but you don't say why. You say " I will have an error" - please show the code that produces the error and the error itself. Otherwise, it is impossible to help you...

Comment: Side note: I fixed a missing `"` and `;` at the end of the `string command = ...` line. I'm assuming that's a typo that doesn't exist in your real code. Feel free to edit the question further if I messed something up.

Comment: At the end of your script : `command +=" order by myorderingcolumn";`

Comment: Don't need to int.Parse a string "3" just so you can compare to number 3.. just compare to string "3". `if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedItem.Value == "3")` or even `if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedValue == "3")`

Comment: @41686d6564 sorry I didn't mention that i want to order by username column my problem is  when i select one of the drop downs or both of them the result will be not sorted

Comment: @Felix if I Added order by at the first string command there will be an error if I selected a drop down value because the order by will be at the middle of the query

Comment: @Hbk88 Well, as Serg suggested, you should add it at the end, not at the beginning. Think about what the full query would be when an item is selected from the dropdown and you'll figure out why it didn't work. Better yet, inspect the value of `command` to actually see what the value is at run time and confirm that it's a valid SQL query.

Comment: @Serg
 your answer was perfect thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var pc = "";
if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedValue == "2")
  pc = " and user_pc >= 1";
else if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedValue == "3")
  pc = " and user_pc = 0";

var lap = "";
if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedValue) == "2")
  lap = " and user_laptop >= 1";
else if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedValue) == "3")
  lap = " and user_laptop = 0";

string command = $@"
SELECT user_name, user_full_name 
FROM users_table 
WHERE user_name > 0 {pc} {lap}
ORDER BY user_name";
```

It's conceptually exactly the same as Serg's suggestion, but keeping the SQL building together makes it a bit clearer to see it as a whole and extend it, in my opinion

One thing I would say; take care that you don't stray into adding user supplied data this way. It's fine to inspect some page value supplied by the user and concat SQL together in a fixed form from hard coded fragments based on the value, but don't be tempted to add a TextBox that searches the description of X..

If you do want to add a TextBox, concatenate a parameter into your SQL:

```
var txt = "";
if(TextBox.Text != "")
  txt = " and somecol LIKE @p1";
```

And then add a parameter with that name and the `TextBox.Text` as the parameter value, when you build the command ...

```
if(TextBox.Text != "")
  command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.Varchar, 100){ Value = TextBox.Text });
```

Comment: thanks @Caius Jard for your effort I tried your code and it worked, also Serg solution was also correct.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer works, I can't recommend it enough, manual string manipulation is a headache and can't scale enough.

Using a Query Builder is the way in such case.

```cs
var query = new Query("users_table")
    .Select("user_name", "user_full_name")
    .Where("user_name", ">", 0)
    .OrderBy("user_name");

if(true /* any condition here */)
{
    query.Where("user_laptop", ">=", 1);
} else {
    query.Where("user_laptop", "=", 0);
}
```

It will generate

```sql
SELECT [user_name], [user_full_name] FROM [users_table] WHERE [user_name] > 0 AND [user_laptop] >= 1 ORDER BY [user_name]
```

Check this [example](https://sqlkata.com/playground?code=var%20query%20%3D%20new%20Query(%22users_table%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Select(%22user_name%22%2C%20%22user_full_name%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Where(%22user_name%22%2C%20%22%3E%22%2C%200)%0A%20%20%20%20.OrderBy(%22user_name%22)%3B%0A%0Aif(true%20%2F*%20any%20condition%20here%20*%2F)%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20query.Where(%22user_laptop%22%2C%20%22%3E%3D%22%2C%201)%3B%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20query.Where(%22user_laptop%22%2C%20%22%3D%22%2C%201)%3B%0A%7D), I've used SqlKata here, but you can choose any Query Builder you want.